# How to stop a Python subprocess using a HTML form button?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm using Django as the web framework. On a single HTML page, I have a form whose purpose is to start a Python subprocess when I click on its submit button. The fields of the form will be filled with parameters which will be passed to this subprocess.

Now, I want to be able to stop the same subprocess using another form button, preferably within the same form. How can I do this? It's probably not that difficult, but I don't know at the moment how to accomplish that in a simple but elegant way. Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean with 'using' the other form button?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would require a web server of sorts on the backend (to handle the post request from the form)... Would using a web server (localhost) be applicable to your issue?

Comment: @JaspervandenBosch: I want to have a single form with two buttons. One button to start the subprocess and one button to stop the same subprocess. But I assume that I need a second form with a single hidden field to accomplish stopping the subprocess, right?

Comment: @ITNinja: This is a project for my master thesis, so it's sufficient for my purposes to use Django's built-in development server.

Comment: @PeterStahl: Perhaps you can accept the answer?

Answer (score 3):

You have to keep a reference to the process in the session. Give each submit button a different "name" attribute, and if this signals stop, kill the subprocess.

```
from subprocess import Popen
if 'start' in request.POST:
    p = Popen("do something")
    request.session['myprocess'] = p
elif 'stop' in request.POST:
    request.session['myprocess'].kill()
```

Form:

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="start" value="start"/>
<input type="submit" name="stop" value="stop"/>
</form>
```

Whether this works depends on your session-storage backend though.

Comment: Method should be `POST`, since it has a clear side-effect on the backend.

Comment: Do you know which session-storage backend works? The default database backend gives me `OSError: [Errno 3] No such process` when I click the button for stopping the subprocess.

Comment: I've tried several session backends now but I always get an `OSError`. What to do?

Comment: @PeterStahl I suggest you post a new question along with the code that you've written.